# Validation Error in Active Admin in Ruby On Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-models

I am trying to add validation in Active Admin model, and doing it as follow:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Skill do

  permit_params :title, :text, :status
  validates :title, length: { maximum: 20 }, presence: true

end
```

and it gives following error:

> undefined method `validates' for # ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:0x007f576cab00c0

When I use same thing on frontend model then it works fine, don't know what's going on.

Comment: can you please paste which active admin version you were using?

Comment: Add validation in the model not in the active admin.

Comment: @power it's 1.0.0.pre4

Comment: @AwladLiton awww! thanks so much :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add validation in the Active record model instead in the active admin.

Add

```
validates :title, length: { maximum: 20 }, presence: true
```

in the `Skill` model